# Workbooks CRM API : Retrieving Contact Details

Tags: c#

We are attempting to access 'Contact Details' within an 'Organisation' via the Workbooks API. When adding them in the Workbooks interface it seems as though they may instead be called 'party_locations' within their system.

The API has plenty of documentation however doesn't seem to cover this section.

So far I have tried the following which gives a separate error that is different to the usual error thrown when the method doesn't exist in their API:

```
var workbooks = new WorkbooksApi(new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "application_name", "..." },
        { "user_agent", "..." },
        { "verify_peer", false },
        { "api_key", "..." },
    });

var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

filters.Add("_start", "0");
filters.Add("_limit", "100");

filters.Add("_sort", "id");
filters.Add("_dir", "ASC");

filters.Add("resource_id", "295994");

var response = workbooks.get("crm/party_locations", filters, null);
var allData = response.getData();
```

Unfortunately this just gives a vary basic error: `We are sorry that there has been an error.\nWorkbooks has recorded the incident with reference: ...`